# How to convert multiple point loads to uniformly distributed load

Tags: beam, load-spreading

So I am working on a project with variables on how many point loads may be applied over a single span.

Both ends are fixed, this is a constant.

For example, I may have a beam which is 6m in overall length and 3 point loads at 10.5KG (I am working in KG for now)

I am trying to figure out the best way for the variables to be able to convert into an equivalent UDL, which will then be used in another formula.

Basically, I am trying to find the number I need to multiply the 1 point load value to get the equivalent UDL.

The example I have been given is:

3 @ 10.5KG is equivalent to 4 x 10.5 / 6 = 7 kg/m

Comment: these two things are not equivalent, you can't just convert one to the other.  Get a better equation.

Comment: You may be able to use superposition. Calculate the stress and/or deflection for each poing load individually and sum the results.

Comment: Have a look at the last answer in this post : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50888/any-way-to-approximate-effect-of-two-point-loads-with-just-one/51923#51923

The post talks about converting a number of point loads to a single equivalent load, but the overall concept is similar and FEA theory already has solutions for it.